# Wordpress contact form 7 frontend confirmation

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I found a template code for contact form 7 on wordpress, after saving the code without getting any error on the contact form edit page, on the frontend of the form after inputting details it keeps bringing an error of sending the message. Here is the code:

```
<fieldset>
<div class="form-group col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
<label class="control-label" for="your-name">Name</label><div class="">
[text* your-name id:name class:form-control class:input-md placeholder 
"Name"]
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
<label class=" control-label" for="email">E-Mail</label><div class="">
[email* email id:email class:form-control class:input-md placeholder "E- 
mail"]
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
<label class="control-label" for="phone">Phone</label><div class="">
[text* phone id:phone class:form-control class:input-md placeholder "Phone"]
</div>
</div>
 <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-sm-12 slide-ranger col-xs-12">
<p id="slider-range-min"></p>
<label for="amount" class="control-label">Loan Amount</label>
[text* amount id:amount readonly class:form-control]
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-6 col-sm-12 slide-ranger col-xs-12">
<p id="slider-range-max"></p>
<label for="amount" class="control-label">Month</label>
[text j id:j readonly class:form-control]
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
<div class="">
[submit id:Submit class:btn class:btn-primary class:btn-block "Submit New 
Quote"]
</div>
</div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: what is the error message you get ?

Comment: There was an error trying to send your message. Please try again later.